# Does a "window of time" get smaller or shorter?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, comparatives

Does a "window of time" get smaller or shorter?

Is there a general rule with such phrases?

Comment: If you look on the internet, you will find that 'short/er', 'small/er' and 'narrow/er' are all used to modify "window of time". But idioms are by their very nature unpredictable in some aspect, and the variability in what 'tinkerings' may acceptably be made is one such aspect.

Comment: Another option: "narrower."